# Rigging issue - The bottom of the torso is moving, where I only want the top to for this bone

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I am new to blender, and I'm trying to make some very simple rigs to test what I've learned. So, I've stopped at the torso(which is only one big resized cube with a loop cut in the middle, no deformation other than that), and as I started moving the armature, I realized the top bone, when rotated, caused the torso to rotate aswell, but it also moved the bottom of it, where it should have moved only the top part. I tried going into weight paint mode to fix this issue but I cant manage to remove weight on the bottom. Could anyone help me please?

---

[image][image]

So the bottom part is deformed aswell when rotating the top bone, where I only want the top part to deform. This object has one loop cut in the middle of it in the Y axis. The bones were linked by automatic weights. I cant seem to figure out how I can remove weight in the weight paint mode.

Comment: A screenshot could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Select the center edge loop in weigh paint mode (use vert mode button in top panel to be able to do that or do it edit mode by going to the vertex group panel and remove the vertex from the vertex group) and set the weight to 0 in the weight slider, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to assign weights (but in this case removing)...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Michael Ben David! Now it works great! The only problem left is this:[image]

So I want it to be constant; The torso parts should always keep the same size, and not be streched this way. Do you(or anyone else) know a way to do this please?[image]

Better example of this problem here ↑

[image]
And what I would like to have: ↑

Comment: You're best off moving these details to your question.  As for the solution to these problems, enable "volume preservation" in your armature modifier.